# Maximum recursion error in `__eq__` implementation

Tags: python

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def getX(self):
        # Getter method for a Coordinate object's x coordinate.
        # Getter methods are better practice than just accessing an attribute directly
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        # Getter method for a Coordinate object's y coordinate
        return self.y

    def __str__(self):
        return '<' + str(self.getX()) + ',' + str(self.getY()) + '>'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.getX == other.getX and self.getY == other.getY:
            return True
        else:
            return False        

c = Coordinate(2, 3)
d = Coordinate(2, 3)

c == d
```

Comment: You forgot to *call* your getter methods: `self.getX` => `self.getX()`. Or better yet, throw those methods away and use properties. Better _yet_, don't use properties either.

Comment: Besides, in Python getter methods aren't considered better practice.

Comment: How is this related to `python-requests` anyway?

Comment: and BTW  `if blah: return True else: return False` is equivalent to `return blah`

Comment: @Aran-Fey that fixes it, but how does it cause infinite recursion?

Comment: @AliYılmaz `self.getX == other.getX` compares two bound methods. Bound methods are considered equal if the method is the same, and the instances they're bound to are equal. So comparing two bound methods also compares the instances, which calls the `__eq__` method again, which compares bound methods again, etc.

Comment: @Aran-Fey oh, I understand it now. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Thanks guys it's worked

Answer (score 1):

Your `__eq__` method should probably be like this:

It avoids comparing objects of different type and alerts of the error immediately, and avoids the use of getters intra class.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.__class__.__name__ == other.__class__.__name__:
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

or in python > 3.3:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.__class__.__qualname__ == other.__class__.__qualname__:
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: we should remove colon ":" mark in return statement.

Comment: Good catch @Martin Thøgersen,  thanks for the edit.