# Design __eq__ that compares __dict__ of self and other safe from RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I've stumbled upon really weird python 3 issue, cause of which I do not understand.

I'd like to compare my objects by checking if all their attributes are equal.

Some of the child classes will have fields that contain references to methods bound to self - and that causes `RecursionError`

Here's the PoC:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.methods = [self.method]
        self.field = field

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return False
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def method(self):
        pass


first = A(field='foo')
second = A(field='bar')

print(first == second)
```

Running the code above in python 3 raises `RecursionError` and I'm not sure why. It seems that the `A.__eq__` is used to compare the functions kept in `self.methods`. So my first question is - why? **Why the object's `__eq__` is called to compare bound function of that object?**

The second question is - **What kind of filter on `__dict__` should I use to protect the `__eq__` from this issue?** I mean - in the PoC above the `self.method` is kept simply in a list, but sometimes it may be in another structure. The filtering would have to include all the possible containers that can hold the self-reference.

One clarification: I do need to keep the `self.method` function in a `self.methods` field. The usecase here is similar to `unittest.TestCase._cleanups` - a stack of methods that are to be called after the test is finished. The framework must be able to run the following code:

```py
# obj is a child instance of the A class

obj.append(obj.child_method)

for method in obj.methods:
    method()
```

Another clarification: the only code I can change is the `__eq__` implementation.

Comment: I tried to run your code and it prints `False`. What python version do you use?

Comment: @SergeyPugach I'm using python 3.7

Comment: Can `self.methods` be different between instances? Does `self.methods` need to contine the same *things* for equality?

Comment: I know you said `__eq__` is the only thing you can change, but: would it be possible to use a custom `list` or `Sequence` subclass for `methods` that does its equality check differently for items in the sequence that are bound methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Why the object's `__eq__` is called to compare bound function of that object?":

Because bound methods compare by the following algorithm:

1. Is the `self` bound to each method equal?
2. If so, is the function implementing the method the same?

Step 1 causes your infinite recursion; in comparing the `__dict__`, it eventually ends up comparing the bound methods, and to do so, it has to compare the objects to each other again, and now you're right back where you started, and it continues forever.

The only "solution"s I can come up with off-hand are:

1. Something like the [`reprlib.recursive_repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.recursive_repr) decorator (which would be extremely hacky, since you'd be heuristically determining if you're comparing for bound method related reasons based on whether `__eq__` was re-entered), or
2. A wrapper for any bound methods you store that replaces equality testing of the respective `self`s with identity testing.

The wrapper for bound methods isn't terrible at least. You'd basically just make a simple wrapper of the form:

```
class IdentityComparableMethod:
    __slots__ = '_method',
    def __new__(cls, method):
        # Using __new__ prevents reinitialization, part of immutability contract
        # that justifies defining __hash__
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self._method = method
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        '''Attribute access should match bound method's'''
        return getattr(self._method, name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        '''Comparable to other instances, and normal methods'''
        if not isinstance(other, (IdentityComparableMethod, types.MethodType)):
            return NotImplemented
        return (self.__self__ is other.__self__ and
                self.__func__ is other.__func__)

    def __hash__(self):
        '''Hash identically to the method'''
        return hash(self._method)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Delegate to method'''
        return self._method(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0.__class__.__name__}({0._method!r})'.format(self)
```

then when storing bound methods, wrap them in that class, e.g.:

```
self.methods = [IdentityComparableMethod(self.method)]
```

You may want to make `methods` itself enforce this via additional magic (so it only stores functions or `IdentityComparableMethod`s), but that's the basic idea.

Other answers address more targeted filtering, this is just a way to make that filtering unnecessary.

Performance note: I didn't heavily optimize for performance; `__getattr__` is the simplest way of reflecting all the attributes of the underlying method. If you want comparisons to go faster, you can fetch out `__self__` during initialization and cache it on `self` directly to avoid `__getattr__` calls, changing the `__slots__` and `__new__` declaration to:

```
    __slots__ = '_method', '__self__'
    def __new__(cls, method):
        # Using __new__ prevents reinitialization, part of immutability contract
        # that justifies defining __hash__
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self._method = method
        self.__self__ = method.__self__
        return self
```

That makes a pretty significant difference in comparison speed; in local `%timeit` tests, the `first == second` comparison dropped from 2.77 μs to 1.05 μs. You could cache `__func__` as well if you like, but since it's the fallback comparison, it's less likely to be checked at all (and you'd slow construction a titch for an optimization you're less likely to use).

Alternatively, instead of caching, you can just manually define `@property`s for `__self__` and `__func__`, which are slower than raw attributes (comparison ran in 1.41 μs), but incur no construction time cost at all (so if no comparison is ever run, you don't pay the lookup cost).

Comment: Even though I cannot use this solution (I cannot monkeypatch the framework to decorate all the methods), I must say: I'm speechless and mind-blown :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `self.methods = [self.method]` and then performing `__eq__` ends up creating a recursion error is nicely explained in one of the comments in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461284/maximum-recursion-error-in-eq-implementation) by @Aran-Fey

> `self.getX == other.getX` compares two bound methods. Bound methods are considered equal if the method is the same, and the instances they're bound to are equal. So comparing two bound methods also compares the instances, which calls the `__eq__` method again, which compares bound methods again, etc

One way to resolve it is to perform key-wise comparison on `self.__dict__` and ignore `methods` key

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, field):

        self.methods = [self.method]
        self.field = field

    def __eq__(self, other):

        #Iterate through all keys
        for key in self.__dict__:
            #Perform comparison on values except the key methods
            if key != 'methods':
                if self.__dict__[key] != other.__dict__[key]:
                    return False

        return True

    def method(self):
        pass


first = A(field='foo')
second = A(field='bar')

print(first == second)
```

The output will be `False`

Comment: That's the whole thing - I **do** need the `self.methods` field. The usecase here is similar to `unittest.TestCase._cleanups` stack of cleanup methods that are called after the test is finished

Comment: Got it, I re-added the line according to a change, please check! Also the cleanup methods should lie outside the class and not inside it. Is `A` a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` ? @Mirek

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, as I'd have use `partial` or pass `self` to those methods when I call them, and that's not an option for my framework. Why the cleanup methods should lie outside of a class? No it's not a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`

Comment: Can you add some code in your method instead of a `pass`, and a dict comparison which fails or passes, and I can see to how I can update the answer

Comment: Also `self.method` will refer to different objects for every instance, so that comparison logic really doesn't work if you do `self.method`

Comment: Yes it will refer to different objects, that's the whole idea - each object has to be able to cleanup itself

Comment: Can you add those details in say `method` object with where you would refer to self as part of logic of `method` @Mirek

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But before you go any further, please note that the only thing I can change is the `__eq__` implementation - the rest of the design is deeply hardcoded in the framework.

Comment: I mean you said `I'd have use partial or pass self to those methods when I call them`, so I am asking to include that scenario in the question itself, so that it's more clear to other answerers too

Comment: I included the code that is executed by the framework

Comment: Cool, I think one way is to ignore `methods` key when iterating over the dictionary and comparing value by value @Mirek please check the updated answer!

Comment: That was my initial idea - but it's not safe enough, it doesn't scale. I don't want to maintain the list of all possible fields similar to `methods`. I want the filter to be "smart" enough to know that it's comparing something that's bound to self or comparing a collection that is bound to self or even comparing a field that is an object that has a field that is bound to self.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193843/discussion-between-devesh-kumar-singh-and-mirek).

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
I think the "==" cause the error. You can install [deepdiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/) and modify your code to:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.methods = [self.method]
        self.field = field

    def __eq__(self, other):
        import deepdiff
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return False
        return deepdiff.DeepDiff(self.__dict__, other.__dict__) == {}

    def method(self):
        pass
```

Then,
`A(field='foo') == A(field='bar')` returns `False`
and
`A(field='foo') == A(field='foo')` returns `True`

---

Original Answer:

Try replacing

```
self.methods = [self.method]
```

with

```
self.methods = [A.method]
```

And the result is `False`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my issue, as I'd have to pass `self` to those methods when I call them, and that's not an option for my framework :(

Comment: @Mirek Hi, do you mean you need to call the `method` function and store the result in variable`methods` when you compare them? Then you can try replacing `self.methods = [self.method]` with `self.methods = [self.method()]`

Comment: I need the method, not a result of a method to be kept in `self.methods`

Comment: @Mirek I think it is what you need is `deepdiff` module, do not simply compare two dicts with `==`.

Comment: Please don't bury imports inside method definitions. Imports should almost always be at the top of the module, unless you have a *very* good reason to put them elsewhere.

Comment: Hmmm... That solution works, thanks! The only reason I hesitate on accepting this as an answer is because it's really heavy - according to `timeit` it's slower by 2 orders of magnitude than the original implementation (stripped from `self.methods` to avoid the exception of course). It's still an order of magnitude faster than catching `RecursionError` (like this https://pastebin.com/1nqFLTUC). If nobody comes with something faster, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're running into is being caused by [a very old bug in CPython](https://bugs.python.org/issue1617161). The good news is that it has already been fixed for Python 3.8 (which will soon be getting its first beta release).

To understand the issue, you need to understand how the equality check for methods from Python 2.5 through 3.7 worked. A bound method has a `self` and a `func` attribute. In the versions of Python where this bug is an issue, a comparison of two bound methods would compare both the `func` and the `self` values for Python-level equality (using the C-API equivalent to the Python `==` operator). With your class, this leads to infinite recursion, since the objects want to compare the bound methods stored in their `methods` lists, and the bound methods need to compare their `self` attributes.

The fixed code uses an identity comparison, rather than an equality comparison, for the `self` attribute of bound method objects. This has additional benefits, as methods of "equal" but not identical objects will no longer be considered equal when they shouldn't be. The motivating example was a set of callbacks. You might want your code to avoid calling the same callback several times if it was registered multiple times, but you wouldn't want to incorrectly skip over a callback if it was bound to an equal (but not identical) object. For instance, two empty containers `append` method registered, and you wouldn't want them to be equal:

```
class MyContainer(list): # inherits == operator and from list, so empty containers are equal
    def append(self, value):
        super().append(value)

callbacks = []
def register_callback(cb):
    if cb not in callbacks:  # this does an == test against all previously registered callbacks
        callbacks.append(cb)

def do_callbacks(*args):
    for cb in callbacks:
        cb(*args)

container1 = MyContainer()
register_callback(container1.append)
container2 = MyContainer()
register_callback(container2.append)

do_callbacks('foo')

print(container1 == container2)   # this should be true, if both callbacks got run
```

The `print` call at the end of the code will output `False` in most recent versions, but in Python 3.8 thanks to the bug fix, it will write `True`, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution I came up with (inspired by @devesh-kumar-singh answer), however it does seem bitter-sweet.

```py
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return False

        for key in self.__dict__:
            try:
                flag = self.__dict__[key] == other.__dict__[key]
                if flag is False:
                    # if one of the attributes is different, the objects are as well
                    return False
            except RecursionError:
                # We stumbled upon an attribute that is somehow bound to self
                pass

        return flag
```

The benefit over @tianbo-ji solution is that it's faster if we find a difference in `__dict__` values before we stuble upon bound method. But if we don't - it's an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: I would say filling out the stack just to catch an exception is not good design :)

Comment: Indeed, it's not. But the chance to not find the difference before is quite small in my project. Also - won't gc clean it up right away?

Comment: You won’t want to optimize considering the current input you have, and design for scale, also depending on a thrown exception to do things for you is better in other cases, perhaps not here :)